# Workaround for crazy string numeric comparison in Qt QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Here is crazy string to numeric comparison in Qt (LTS 5.6.2) QML JavaScript implementaion:

```
console.log("240000000000" == "3776798720");
console.log("240000000000" === "3776798720");
console.log("240000000000" === "3776798721");
```

And the output is:

```
true
true
false
```

It looks like string interpreted as (u)int32 and high byte lost:

```
240000000000 == 0x37E11D6000
3776798720   ==   0xE11D6000
```

This bug also effects on objects:

```
var g = {};
var h = "240000000000";
g[h] = h + "BUG";
console.log(JSON.stringify(g, null, 2));
console.log(g["3776798720"], g["240000000000"]);
```

Output:

```
qml: {
    "3776798720": "240000000000BUG"
}
qml: 240000000000BUG 240000000000BUG
```

As you can see the key is damaged. The value can be obtained by two different strings.

### Question

Is there any option to get some workaround with this without patching Qt? Or at least the approximate location where can be the problem in Qt to improve yourself?

p.s. Also here is a [QTBUG-56830](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56830) reported by my coworker.

Comment: Does it also happen if the environment variable `QV4_FORCE_INTERPRETER' is set to 1?

Comment: Is this a bug, or is this mandated by the ecmascript standard?

Comment: @peppe Does not affect the results.

Comment: Kuba Ober I reviewed the ecmascript 5.1 and can't find anything like that. Looks like a Qt bug. And it is not clear in what place.

Comment: @KubaOber ECMA states that property name should always be a string and when you access a property via something else than a string literal then ToString() method shall be used to obtain string value. (11.2.1 , 11.1.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a workaround, so I've made a fix: apply to qtdeclarative the patch that I've posted here

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/175782

And recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's workaround that seems to work

```
console.log(String("3776798720").localeCompare("240000000000") === 0)
console.log(String("3776798721").localeCompare("240000000000") === 0)
console.log(String("240000000000").localeCompare("240000000000") === 0)
```

Output:

```
qml: false
qml: false
qml: true
```

Or if you have string variable

```
var str = "3776798720"
console.log(str.localeCompare("240000000000") === 0)
```

Comment: doc the bug is not in only comparision. The key case with objects is most critical. And cant be fixed with localeCompare.

Comment: @misterion yeah, but you asked if there's workaround for string numeric comparison, so I have provided an answer. For objects I don't see a workaround except of registering your own QML type from C++ (exposing `QJsonObject` interface for example) to address the issues. For built-in objects, as you pointed out, numeric string is converted to `int`, which I think is incorrect and is a bug indeed.